# loading x3dom html file is not working in android webview

Tags: android, webview, x3dom

I am trying to load x3dom html file in android web view. when I try to load x3dom file in browser "chrome" in android it works fine. But when I load it in web View the scene is not full showing. I update web view but still not working. Its controls works fine but it shows only small portion of the scene. The same thing happens when I load three.js website 3d examples in web view. As there any custom web view which support WEBGL fully like browser. Or any other Help will be appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use AdvancedWebView. You can find that on GitHub.

Comment: I tried but no luck. I think advance webView using the Same WebView but customizing few listeners.

Comment: Then try to use CrossWalk Webview.

Comment: I have already done that..And thank you so much..Its working now